# Why can only the moderators see the updated FAQs?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange, stackexchange-2.0, moderator-abilities

I got all excited today when I saw an "edit" link our cooking SE FAQ and went straight to work on it - even dug up an old post asking for the FAQ to be updated and marked it `[status-complete]`.

Then people were saying nothing had changed, and it turned out that only the moderators can see the new FAQ!  All other users see the original.

Is this intentional?  Is this further "moderated" by the team, or is it just a buggy/incomplete feature?

Comment: Same situation on WebApps.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doh - we cache pretty aggressively on the sites and the old /faq version wasn't being removed.

A fix will be pushed tonight, honest!

Comment: Interesting... why *can* the moderators see it then, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Aarobot the /faq page isn't cached for moderators, allowing the edit controls to be loaded.